# Syntax on Constructors with Const Members

Tags: c++, constants

I haven't done C++ coding in some time, and my friend is having trouble with his homework. I never really worked with `const`, and it's making this a nightmare as I can't figure out the correct syntax for the constructor. Imagine I have this in `dvd.h`:

```
class DVD {
    const string title;
    int minutes;
    double price;

  public:
    DVD(const string t, int m, double p);
}
```

3 private member variables, the `string` is `const`. The constructor also takes a `const string`.

So now, in `dvd.cpp` I can do the following:

```
#include "dvd.h"

DVD::DVD(const string t, int m, double p) {
    const string title = t;
    minutes = m;
    price = p;
}
```

And all is well in the world. However, when I modify `minutes` in `dvd.h` to be `const` (which is how his professor structured the file), we have this in `dvd.h`:

```
class DVD {
    const string title;
    const int minutes; // Here is the change
    double price;

  public:
    DVD(const string t, int m, double p);
}
```

So, now that `minutes` is `const`, I get the following compilation errors:

```
assignment of read-only member 'DVD::minutes'   dvd.cpp
uninitialized member 'DVD::minutes' with 'const' type 'const int' [-fpermissive]    dvd.cpp
```

Which I suppose makes sense, because I'm trying to *set* a value into a `const` variable. So then I tried doing the same thing as with the `const string title` in `dvd.cpp` in order to resolve the error:

```
DVD::DVD(const string t, int m, double p) {
    const string title = t;
    const int minutes = m; // Was 'minutes = m;'
    price = p;
}
```

and got the following (1) errors and (1) warnings:

```
uninitialized member 'DVD::minutes' with 'const' type 'const int' [-fpermissive]    dvd.cpp
unused variable 'minutes' [-Wunused-variable]   dvd.cpp
```

So I guess I'm struggling to figure out *what the darn syntax is* for this... `title` and `minutes` are supposed to be `const`, but the constructor's parameter list for `DVD` takes only a `const string`. I can't figure out what I'm missing - it's been a while since I last coded in C++.

Comment: Get used to member initialization X : member(value) {]

Comment: The syntax is always the same: if you want to *initialize* data members in some particular way, you do it in the constructor initialization list (although you can also do it at the point of declaration in C++11). What happens is that you cannot *assign* or modify `const` data members.

Comment: @Csq You're probably right - like I said, it's been a long time since I last did C++. I completely forgot about initializer lists. It's interesting, I looked at the question linked by WhozCraig (before I posted this question), and I didn't really understand it when I read it. In any case, I understand it now so thank you for the comments :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const string title = t;
```

That declares a local variable. All is not well with the world: you haven't set the member variable to the value you want. To initialise members, use the constructor's initialiser list:

```
DVD::DVD(const string t, int m, double p) :
    title(t), minutes(m), price(p)
{}
```

Your version tries to *default-initialise* each member (since they aren't mentioned in the initialiser list), then *assign* each of them. This doesn't work for members which can't be default-initialised (such as references, or class types without a default constructor) or assigned to (such as `const` members).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - what I *tried* to do is the usual way constructors work in the languages the I usually use, and I couldn't remember exactly how it was done in C++. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize your `const` and non-`const` members simply like this:

```
DVD::DVD(const string t, int m, double p)
    : title(t)
    , minutes(m)
    , price(p)
{}
```

Note that, if you are using C++98/03, you may want to pass the `string` parameter as `const&` (to avoid useless and inefficient calls to string copy constructor):

```
DVD(const string& t, ...other stuff...)
    ... same init as above
```

If you are using C++11 (which implements *move semantics*), you can pass the string parameter by value, and `std::move()` from the value:

```
DVD::DVD(string t, int m, double p)
    : title(std::move(t)),
    , minutes(m)
    , price(p)
{}
```